# What is the timeline of the parasite invasion in ST:TNG's "Conspiracy"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode Coming of Age, Picard's Enterprise is thoroughly investigated by Lt Cmdr Remmick at the direction of Admiral Quinn. Remmick gives Picard a good report, and afterwards, Quinn and Picard have this conversation:

> QUINN: Some of us at Starfleet Command became suspicious of certain problems in the Federation.
> PICARD: What kind of problems?
> QUINN: Something or someone is trying to destroy the fabric of everything we've built up in the last two hundred years.
> PICARD: What's your evidence?
> QUINN: I can't go into that. There are too many people involved.

A few months later, in Conspiracy, Remmick is not only possessed by one of the parasites, but has become host mother for a horde of them.

It seems clear that Remmick is not under parasite control in "Coming of Age," but the situation that Quinn is talking about seems to be due to the parasites.

What's the timeline here - were a significant number of parasites possessing Starfleet officers before Remmick became host-mother? Was Remmick host-mother without being controlled (or was Remmick fully under control and just acting very human in spite of it)? Or was Quinn mistaken (or lying under parasite control already)?

Are there any canonical or quasi-canonical details on this?